# how to check that phone was shut down by battery removal

Tags: android

I have searched everywhere but no answer found, is there any way in android to check that Last shutdown was by removing battery in Android?

**For example**
If I just take out battery of my running phone, upon next boot is there any way to tell that phone was not shutdown properly.

I am sure there will be any flag that keep track of device is running and when we ask android to shutdown by UI it will set the flag to shutdown.

Comment: plz give me reason for down-vote guys??? its not helping me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a **BroadcastReceiver** which is triggered by the action `android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN`.

If the device is shut down normally then it will run. If shutdown by a battery removal, then it won't. You can then write some semaphore code to suit your purposes, perhaps using another BroadcastReceiver for `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` to check it on start up.

Comment: Thanks @NickT Thats great `android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN` is the way